# How to update the Record based on other table

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I want to update the record based on other table's condition with sequelize, please have a look the example

[image]

Now i want to update the Student Subjects where student name is "isha"

How can i set update condition with pure sequelize method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have two model classes, `Students` and `StudentSubject`. I also assume you defined an association between these models, keeping the default generated getters and setters. You can do the following:

```
Students.findOne({
  where: {
    name: 'isha'
  }
}).then(student => {
  StudentSubject[] subjects = await Students.getSubjects();
  subjects.forEach(subject => {
    await subject.update(/* Your update here*/);
    await subject.save();
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, So must have to fire 2 query for this, actually i was looking for one query. Thank You.